# Spark: RDD to List

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD structure

```
RDD[(String, String)]
```

and I want to create 2 Lists (one for each dimension of the rdd).

I tried to use the rdd.foreach() and fill two ListBuffers and then convert them to Lists, but I guess each node creates its own ListBuffer because after the iteration the BufferLists are empty. How can I do it ?

EDIT : my approach

```
val labeled = data_labeled.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(',')
  (parts(5), parts(7))
}.cache()

var testList : ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer()

labeled.foreach(line =>
  testList += line._1
)
  val labeledList = testList.toList
  println("rdd: " + labeled.count)
  println("bufferList: " + testList.size)
  println("list: " + labeledList.size)
```

and the result is:

```
rdd: 31990654
bufferList: 0
list: 0
```

Comment: Please update with the code of what you have tried and some input data sample and expected output ! Your question is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you really want to create two *Lists* - meaning, you want all the distributed data to be collected into the driver application (risking slowness or `OutOfMemoryError`) - you can use `collect` and then use simple `map` operations on the result:

```
val list: List[(String, String)] = rdd.collect().toList
val col1: List[String] = list.map(_._1)
val col2: List[String] = list.map(_._2)
```

Alternatively - if you want to "split" your RDD into two *RDDs* - it's pretty similar without collecting the data:

```
rdd.cache() // to make sure calculation of rdd is not repeated twice
val rdd1: RDD[String] = rdd.map(_._1)
val rdd2: RDD[String] = rdd.map(_._2)
```

A third alternative is to first map into these two RDDs and then collect each one of them, but it's not much different from the first option and suffers from the same risks and limitations.

Comment: @Yuriy How come broadcast variable(which is read-only) related to here? Can you describe it more?

Comment: @avr ListBuffer is mutable and `+=` mutate inner state, not create new reference. But you question is good, and for immutable statement (where reference changing for any operation) need to wrap it with something (Serializable). Simple example for List: `val testList = sc.broadcast(new Serializable { var list = List.empty[String] })`, and after mutate internal state.

Comment: @Yuriy I think avr is right and you misunderstood his/her question - it's not a matter of mutable vs. immutable collection - broadcast variables are _read only_ in the sense that if their values are changed on an executor, the driver code won't see this change (how would Spark aggregate the changes made by all executors?). The fact that this works in local mode looks mostly like a bug, it won't work where the cluster is actually distributed.

Comment: You right, I missed this point. Removed my changes, sorry for noise.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Tzach Zohar's answer, you can use `unzip` on the lists:

```
scala> val myRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", "b"), ("c", "d")))
myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:27

scala> val (l1, l2) = myRDD.collect.toList.unzip
l1: List[String] = List(a, c)
l2: List[String] = List(b, d)
```

Or `keys` and `values` on the `RDD`s:

```
scala> val (rdd1, rdd2) = (myRDD.keys, myRDD.values)
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at keys at <console>:33
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at values at <console>:33

scala> rdd1.foreach{println}
a
c

scala> rdd2.foreach{println}
d
b
```